# Question mark or period at the end of "What is your favorite song, and explain why"

Tags: grammar, question-mark

Which would be correct?

> What is your favorite song, and explain why? (I'm thinking this is right.)
>    What is your favorite
>   song, and explain why.

This could be written as, "What is your favorite song? Explain why." But that seems kind of clunky. Looking at similar questions on this site I see that maybe there isn't a great answer to this (or maybe that this question is more straight forward than what I was looking at). I dislike the *Chicago Manual of Style* format, so ideally one of the two choices above would be correct.

Answer (score 5):

I consider both options you provided incorrect. If you really wanted to avoid writing the correct

> What is your favourite song? Explain why.

you can write

> What is your favourite song, and why?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question came from investigating the grammar of a question I had on a test ("Which choice will produce..., and explain why."). You helped clear it up for me, so thank you.

Comment: Okay, you'd avoid both, but which is correct?

Comment: @Insane Neither is correct. Both are completely ungrammatical. _And_ cannot be used to join a question with a statement, though it can (perhaps somewhat inelegantly) be used to join a statement with a question in some contexts.